# ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate got delayed after several iterations

Tags: java, delay, infinite-loop, schedule, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a delay problem implementing ScheduledExecutorService (specifically scheduleAtFixedRate).

The program must show a JLabel (which contain an image) and then after 3.5 seconds hide it and show another JLabel (also with an image) and 3.5 seconds after hide it and show the first one again, and do it all over again in an infinite-loop.

So here's my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CyclicImages extends javax.swing.JFrame {

boolean flag = false;  

public CyclicImages() {
    initComponents();
    //This two lines are in my class constructor
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(cyclic, 3500, 3500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

Runnable cyclic = new Runnable() {   
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
               if(flag == false) {
                    imgFirst.setVisible(false);
                    imgSecond.setVisible(true);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    imgSecond.setVisible(false);
                    imgFirst.setVisible(true);
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
 }
```

So then, if I run the program it works great for like 6 or 7 iterations then is delayed over and over and loses the 3.5 seconds parameter.

My question here is, why is this happening in a ScheduledExecutorService? It is not supposed to never happen unlike the thread.sleep() method?

Note: I'm not using any event (actionPerfomed, etc.) to start the schedule.

Update: I changed the scheduleAtFixedRate line for this: `executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(cyclic, 3500, 3500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` and also removed the `while(true)` loop with their respective breaks, but my program is still delayed.

Comment: What is the use of `false == false` condition? It seems wrong to me.

Comment: @akhil_mittal Oh yeah, sorry my mistake, I wrote it wrong, must say `flag == false` I already corrected.

Comment: Shouldn't you should be using scheduleWithFixedDelay ?

Comment: @geekprogrammer Well I changed and is actually working better (like 10 iterations without delay) but still got delayed after the 11 iteration.

Comment: Why are you using While(true) ?? it's pointless

Comment: @SercanOzdemir You're right, Now is removed. Still the "main" problem persists.